# @media landscape working but min-width and max-width aren't

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `@media` to change te background image of my website

Somehow when I use `@media  (orientation: landscape)` is works fine but when I use min and max width is doesn't show any background

I inserted 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
in the page that uses the css file.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1501px) and (max-width: 6000px)  {
body {
/* this one doesn't work*/
background: url(/afbeeldingen/overzichtskaart.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*background-size: 100% 100%*/
}
}

@media screen (max-width: 1500px) and {
body {
/* this one doesn't work*/
background: url(/afbeeldingen/overzichtskaart_laptop.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*background-size: 100% 100%*/
}
}

@media  (orientation: landscape) {
body {
/* this one does work*/
background: url(/afbeeldingen/overzichtskaart_laptop.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*background-size: 100% 100%*/
}
}
```

I don't want to use the landscape option but change backgrounds based on the width size.

Comment: the second one isn't working because your'e having extra `and` try to remove it and it should work.

for the first one, are you sure youre opening youre website with screen-width more than 1500px ??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is wrong. The correct syntax is `@media only screen and (min-width: 1501px) and (max-width: 6000px)` and `@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px)`.

Try this:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1501px) and (max-width: 6000px) {
  body {
    background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  body {
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500382017468-9049fed747ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
```

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Its just because you are not writing your css properly. Below example might be helpful for you.

```css
@media screen and (min-width:1501px) and (max-width:6000px)  {
h1{

background-color:red;

}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
h1 {
background-color:green;
}
}
```

```html
<h1>This is test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that commenting syntax in your original CSS, this might be part of the cause for your troubles: `//` at the start of the line won't work for comments in CSS. Comments in CSS have to be writte as `/*  ... your code ... */`.

And your second CSS rule shouldn't have `@media screen (max-width: 1500px) and {...` as a selector, but instead `@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {...` (i.e. wrong order)